# Access to an attribute of a class when the name is a reserved keyword- Python

Tags: python, api, class, syntax-error

I have a "item" object (<class 'zenpy.lib.api_objects.Comment'>) coming from an API call (JSON) like this:

```
{
"id": 1,
"type": 10,
"via": {
     "from":{
        "id": "511",
        "name": "a"
     },
     "to":{
        "id": "999",
        "name": "b"
     }
   }
}
```

So, when I do

```
print(item.via.to['id'])
```

it works properly, but when I try to do:

```
print(item.via.from['id'])
```

I'm getting an error SyntaxError: invalid syntax on the "from". Because is a reserved keyword.

How can I access to that value? I can't change the "from" name because is coming from an API call.

Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `item.via.from` ?

Comment: is it JSON or a class?

Comment: `getattr(item.via, 'from').id` maybe, but you really must provide a [mcve]

Comment: @rdas you are right, I've written it here wrong, sorry.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm getting: AttributeError: 'via' object has no attribute 'from'

Comment: @ToninoFernandez then it has no attribute `from`.

Comment: @gold_cy is coming from an API call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peeking through the code of the API you are referencing, it looks like reserved words the convention for their classes is to prefix it with a leading `_` ([looking here](https://github.com/facetoe/zenpy/blob/72057d0a01cd5a5c696b00e28e2790ef7d7ea2fa/zenpy/lib/api_objects/__init__.py#L98))

So try using `item.via._from`, the _from is a valid identifier.

Could also be best to call the `to_dict` or even actual lower-level `__dict__` on the object and access it by string, but I think the first should work:

```py
x = item.via._from.id


x = item.to_dict()["via"]["from"]["id"]

# or worst case…

x = item.via.__dict__["from"].id
```

Comment: item.via._from didn't work. But item.via.from_ it worked :), also the to_dict function worked